# Make two widgets aligned to top center Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have tried to achieve this widget but nothing is working:
[image]

is it possible to create it?

Comment: your given image is not clear. are you trying to show something as overlay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this, in case you are trying to put a widget over another.

```
Container(
        width: 100,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, top: 16),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned(
              top: 20,
              child: Container(
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
                color: Colors.red
              )
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 0,
              left: 10, 
              right: 10,
              child: Container(
                height: 40,
                color: Colors.green
              )
            ),
          ]
        ),
      )
```